# Is this approach to solve this probability problem correct?

Tags: probability, solution-verification

An urn contains 3 red and 7 black balls. Players $A$ and $B$ withdraw balls from the urn consecutively until a red ball is selected. Find the probability that $A$ selects the red ball. $A$ draws the first ball, then $B$, and so on. There is no replacement of the balls drawn.

Let $A^F$ denote the event that $A$ draws a black ball. Similarly for $B$.

My answer will be $A$ + $A^F.B^F.A$ +...
This is possible as long as the black balls aren’t exhausted. I got 4 such terms which I added and my answer is $0.3+0.175+0.0833+0.025=0.5833$
Is this correct?
Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: 0.3 is correct but it is not correct after that. A gets a second turn only if both A and B fetch black balls in the first round. So, (7/10 x 6/9 x 3/8) will be the second turn similarly calculate till his 4th turn.

Comment: But the term that you wrote (7/10 x 6/9 x 3/8) equals 0.175? I’m confused.

Comment: Never mind. My calculation mistake :) then your approach is fine.

Comment: Okay okay! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your method, I compute the probability that $A$ wins on his first turn, $A$ wins on his second turn, etc. to be

- $3/10$
- $0.175$
- $0.08333...$
- $0.025$

which agrees with the probabilities you found. The other way you can do this question is to see that this probability is same as the probability that a random arrangement of the 10 balls has the leftmost red ball in an odd-numbered position.

The number of ways to arrange 7 black and 3 red balls is $10 \choose 3$. The number of ways to arrange the balls with the leftmost red ball in an odd position is
$$ {9 \choose 2} + {7 \choose 2} + {5 \choose 2} + {3 \choose 2} = 70 $$
The final answer is then $70 / 120 = 0.58\dot{3}$.

Comment: This is cleaner and less tedious, thanks!